# Modify table structure (merge cells) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table

```
<table>
<tr><td>9:00</td><td id='ts9'>task1</td></tr>
<tr><td>10:00</td><td id='ts10'></td></tr>
<tr><td>11:00</td><td id='ts11'>task2</td></tr>
<tr><td>12:00</td><td id='ts12'>task3</td></tr>
</table>
```

and I need to merge cells with id 10 and 11 in one because that task takes 2 hours. I am using jQuery.

I thought about:

```
$("#ts9").attr('colSpan', 2);
```

But it wont work.

Answer (score 4):

If you must use jQuery, then this works:

```
$('#ts10')
    .text($('#ts11').text())
    .attr('rowspan','2')
    .closest('tbody')
    .find('#ts11')
    .remove();​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cBeTz/1/).

Or, somewhat more concisely:

```
$('#ts10')
    .text($('#ts11').remove().text())
    .attr('rowspan','2');​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cBeTz/2/).

And a slightly more...useful approach, which will merge cells of adjacent rows with the `class` of `two`:

```
$('tr td.two').each(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            next = that.parent().next().find('.two');
        if (next.length){
            that
                .text(next.remove().text())
                .attr('rowspan','2');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cBeTz/3/).

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Merges cells with same text: Logic: for each cell, if next cell same text, remove next cell, increment colSpan. (Note "colSpan", not "colspan" - apparently a browser compat issue)

```
$('#tblData tbody tr:first-child td').each(function(){
 var colSpan=1;
 while( $(this).text() == $(this).next().text() ){
  $(this).next().remove();
  colSpan++;
 }
$(this).attr('colSpan',colSpan);
});
```

Comment: I think this approach looks good, but I can´t make it fully work, it only merges for the first row in my case, Can you please update it to check all rows? also, on my case, I would like to make it check rowSpan (top to bottom), will it help if I just change colSpan to rowSpan? or should I do something else?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to add **rowspan** to ds10 and then **remove** ts11 from the second row here. Change you code from colspan to rowspan, add the following

```
$("#ts11").remove();
```

and you should get result you need. 
But i didn't personally try changing rowspan/colspan attributes via jquery, i'm just assuming it works well. Hope it helps.

p.s.: corrected numbers, thought u need to merge 9 and 10 first :)