# Merging many cells

Tags: jquery, html

I need to know how to merge many existed cells in jQuery by using Id.
this is an small example of my table:

```
<body>
  <table>
     <tr id='tr0'>
        <td id='td0_0'></td>
        <td id='td0_1'></td>
        <td id='td0_2'></td>
     <tr>
     <tr id ='tr1'>
        <td id='td1_1'></td>
        <td id='td1_1'></td>
        <td id='td1_2'></td>
     <tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: 1. What did you try? 2. What do you mean by merging>?

Comment: I mean fusion of cells

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219242/modify-table-structure-merge-cells-with-jquery

Comment: You want to merge all of the cells into a new table? Or you want to merge (add) the contents of each cell into a single value?

Comment: do the IDs actually matter, or do you just want to coalesce all of the cells in each row into a single cell?

Comment: Why don't you post the html you want to end up with, as your description doesn't mean anything.

Comment: for example: I want to merge 2 existed cells in row0 and 4 in row3 ... is it possible?

Comment: @RadouaneFadel that doesn't help - you need to indicate _how_ the HTML code specifies which cells are supposed to be merged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming for now (since the question doesn't tell us) that you want to coalesce each cell's contents into the first column:

```
$('#mytable tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    var $siblings = $(this).nextAll();
    $siblings.contents().appendTo(this);
    $siblings.remove();
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/BKyTj/

If the IDs of the set of cells to be merged is known instead, you can still use a variation of the inner code above to merge each group of cells, e.g.:

```
my $merge = $('#cell1 #cell2 #cell3');
my $first = $merge.eq(0);
my $siblings = $merge.slice(1);
$siblings.contents().appendTo($first);
$siblings.remove();
$first.attr('colspan', $merge.length);  // to preserve table layout
```

Comment: in each row I have a different number of cells to coalesce