# how to merge any number of(dyanamic) table cells who has a same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to to merge table cells who has a same class using jquery,how can I do that?and here the number of cells merging is not fixes,any one have any clue?

My HTMl is Like

```
<table>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>text</td> 
            <td class="row">text</td>
            <td class="row">text</td>
            <td class="row">text</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>text</td> 
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="row">text</td> 
            <td class="row">text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>       
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

am expecting output like
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _"merge table cells"_ ? What is expected output ?

Comment: means wants to make a single cell of all those cells who has a same class
it's colpsan property in HTML

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219242/modify-table-structure-merge-cells-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop the table rows, check if there are multiple `.row` table cells. If so, add a colspan to the first, and remove the other. Note that the text of these cells will also be removed.

```js
$(function() {
  $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    var colspan = $(this).find('td.row').length;
    if( colspan > 1 ) {
      $(this).find('td.row:first').attr('colspan', colspan);
      $(this).find('td.row:not(:first)').remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## grouped wrapped

```js
$(function() {
  $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      if( $(this).attr('class') ) {
        var cls = $(this).attr('class'),
            nextCells = $(this).nextUntil('td:not(.'+cls+')'),
            colspan = nextCells.length+1;
        if( colspan > 1 ) {
          $(this).attr('colspan', colspan);
          nextCells.remove();
        }
      }      
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks this is realy helpfull for me,but this has small issue and that is whn we have HTMl structure like,<tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td >text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
     <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
      <td class="row">text</td>
    </tr>,then it should merge 2 cells then should have left 3 un-merged cells and then should merge rest of 4 cells but it is merging 6 cells continuesly rather it should do it separatly.

Comment: for more clear understanding please check this(http://i.stack.imgur.com/JKKsp.png) link of image snapp

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in following way... 
you have to create object for each class in traversing of each `tr` element, and join text of each grouped class in first cell and apply col-span

**It supports multiple groups of different class in one row**

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
  var group_cell={};
  $(this).find('td[class]').each(function(){
      var classname=$(this).attr('class');
      if(typeof group_cell[classname]==="undefined"){
        group_cell[classname]=[];
      }
      group_cell[classname].push($(this).text());
  });
  for(i in group_cell){
      $(this).find('td[class="'+i+'"]:first').text(group_cell[i][0]).attr('colspan',group_cell[i].length);
//OR
//$(this).find('td[class="'+i+'"]:first').text(group_cell[i].join(' ')).attr('colspan',group_cell[i].length);
      $(this).find('td[class="'+i+'"]').not(':first').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspeccing=1>
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>text</td> 
            <td class="row">text</td>
            <td class="row">text</td>
            <td class="row">text</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="group1">text</td> 
            <td class="group2">text</td>
            <td class="group3">text</td>
            <td class="group4">text</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="row">text</td> 
            <td class="row">text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>       
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for upvote, but I have added one more feature by contains multiple class groups you can check it by executing code snippet preview and change class name

Comment: Answer from LinkinTED is correct for only one class, but you had asked in question `who has a same class?`

Comment: thanks buddy i really apriciate your answer and am sorry about question where i forgot to mension cells merging for single class or multiple class.here i have td in table who has two classes e.g "abc" and "pqr" and i want to merge only those cells who has "abc" class and i want to keep cells of "pqr" as it is, i tried your code that merge all cells who has contains same class